# Possible to have Winston to include which logger that created the entry?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, winston

The below PoC outputs

```
{"clock":"aaaa","id":"bbb","state":"ccc","level":"info","message":"Down","timestamp":"2021-02-04 15:25:25"}
```

but it doesn't include which logger that wrote the entry. Ie. in this case it was `monitorLogger.info()`. The `info` part is represented in the `level` tag, but the entry doesn't mention `monitorLogger`.

## Question

Is it possible to get `winston` to include a tag of which logger that created the entry?

**check.js**

```
const {monitorLogger} = require('./logger');

monitorLogger.info('Down', {
  clock: 'aaaa',
  id: 'bbb',
  state: 'ccc'
});
```

**logger.js**

```
const { createLogger, format, transports, config } = require('winston');

const monitor = createLogger({
  transports: [
    new transports.Console()
  ],
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    format.json(),
  ),
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.Console()
  ]
});

module.exports = {
 monitorLogger: monitor
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the createlogger, can we add a label like below

```
const { createLogger, format, transports, config } = require('winston');

const { combine, timestamp, label, json } = format; // <---- additional import

const monitor = createLogger({
  transports: [
    new transports.Console()
  ],
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    format.json(),
    label({ label: 'monitor' })
  ),
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.Console()
  ]
});

module.exports = {
 monitorLogger: monitor
};

Sample output would be

{"clock":"aaaa","id":"bbb","state":"ccc","level":"info","message":"Down","label":"monitor","timestamp":"2021-02-04 15:25:25"}
```

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: label is not defined` and the json youpost doesn't seam to be valid.

Comment: Hey Sandra you may need to import label from format.       
const { combine, timestamp, label} = format;

Comment: I have updated the additional import you will need @SandraSchlichting.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { createLogger, format, transports, config } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, json } = format;

const monitor = createLogger({
  transports: [
    new transports.Console()
  ],
  format: combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    label({ label: 'monitor' }),
    timestamp(),
    json(),
  ),
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.Console()
  ]
});

module.exports = {
 monitorLogger: monitor
};
```

gives

```
{"clock":"aaaa","id":"bbb","state":"ccc","level":"info","message":"Down","timestamp":"2021-02-04 21:32:54","label":"monitor"}
```